# XCode - GitHub ´SecureTransport error: I/O error. (-1)´

Tags: ios, xcode, github, push, secure-transport

I'm having an issue when `pushing` to my GitHub repo (it's an iOS app for iPhone). I haven't had any problem doing this in the last few years. However, without changing anything related to the connection between XCode and GitHub, now I get this error message:

[image]

I've checked and all my credentials are up to date, the project is working fine, and I'm able to do `commits`, but when I do the `push`. The error appears and no push is done.

Furthermore, I've tried pushing other projects and there is no problem. Also, the push size is not that big.

What should I do to solve this error? I'm using the `Source Control` functionality of XCode.

Comment: Try the command line instead and ask for verbose output.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that it changed with command line. I discovered that there is a file with +100mb and that's why it is rejected.

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to answer your own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing the `push` through command line (terminal), I found out that the error was produced due to a file that had a size of +100MB. I had to remove it and everything went fine.

Remark: That file was a `pod` library. So, be careful when pushing all your project. At the end, to backup the whole project you just need the `podfile`, as it is the one you use to install pod libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue cause of selecting different origin, select default origin and Source Control > Push and select Origin in dropdown then push

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue then I used terminal and I realised that I needed to add my personal access token to my push request.

*To get your personal access token, go to your github.com account->profile->Settings->Developer settings->Personal access tokens and generate a new token. Save somewhere safe as you can only copy once else you have to regenerate again*

> Initialising and committing your project locally. **Skip if you've already committed**

```
cd <directory of your project>
git init
git add .
git commit -m "type in a commit message here"
```

> Pushing to your remote project on github.com

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/AccountName/testProject.git
git push -u origin master
```

> It'll prompt you to enter Username & Password but password should be your token already created on github prior and NOT your account password

```
Username for 'https://github.com': <your username here>
Password for '<your username is shown here>': <access token here>
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched off VPN and successfully pushed

Comment: Interesting, the same error and so multiple solutions! XCode should improve their error messaging.